# How can I name Movieclips in a Movieclip from a Class in Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air

I have a lot the same Movieclips placed inside a Movieclip.  I want to name them, but doing it by hand for each of them would be an annoying task, so I want to do it through actionscript.

I have a Movieclip class named `item_Potion` ***(unrelated)***, and when it runs the constructor function we add 1 to a global variable named `itemNumber`, then we make the name `name = String("item" + itemNumber);` in simple terms, we make it `item + itemNumber`

Just to be clear, this class is bound to this Movieclip item_Potion.

**Now here is the issue:**

When I try changing the name by doing `name = String("item" + itemNumber);` I get the following error:

```
Error: Error #2078: The name property of a Timeline-placed object cannot be modified.
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/set name()
    at item_Potion()[E:\g\item_Potion.as:33]
    at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
    at flash.display::Sprite()
    at flash.display::MovieClip()
    at mc_Map()[E:\g\mc_Map.as:15]
    at Game()[E:\g\Game.as:82]
```

So this is now my question, how can I name the Movieclips from the class without the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of the "*`name` property of a Timeline-placed object*" as a *"variable token"* that will reference the object, thus needs to be immutable as the error message states!

---

A rational workaround would be to assign the objects with a custom class (probably derived from the [`MovieClip`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html) class) in which a dedicated field is there to hold the specific *name* of the object:

```
public class MySpecialMC extends MovieClip {
    public var objName:String;
}
```

A *quick* workaround would be to provide the objects with the [dynamic class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f89.html) of the very [`MovieClip`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html) class and store the "*name*" in a dynamic property:

```
myObj['objName'] = 'item' + itemNumber;
```